# Imported JS file - ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Pagination is undeclared

Tags: javascript, function, compiler-errors, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Google Closure's advanced compiler and I get returned the following error.app.js:3:

```
 ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Pagination is undeclared
  const pagination        = Pagination();
                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this....

`Pagination()` relates to a seperate JS file I have - pagination.js - where I'm storing/importing a load of functions.

And `const pagination = Pagination();`, is where I'm calling/using these functions in a seperate app.js file.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks,
Reena

Comment: Please try to import pagination.js in your app.js

Comment: @AyushKatiyar - Do you mean like this?  
import { Pagination } from 'pagination.js';
  const pagination           = Pagination();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @mrstack999 - User error, but I realised all I needed to do, was compile the second file also :p

So sorry, but thank you for your help and time :)

```
npx google-closure-compiler --js=app.js --js=pagination.js  --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js_output_file=minified.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is found in another file, you have to import it in the current file. First, make sure that the `Pagination` function is properly exported from `pagination.js`. Then import it into `app.js`. It's only after you import it that you can call it.

The exact syntax for importing/exporting depends on the enviornment you're working in - Node, browser transpiled with Babel, browser with ES5, etc. So make sure to Google.

Comment: @mrsack999 - Hiya, this is what I've done.  I've imported Pagination().  And then I'm calling the functions in the same file it's imported to, app.js.  My code works fine, however the compilation breaks here...

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear to me that the function was being imported, so I apologize. In that case, I'd have to see more of the code in order to know what's going on.

Comment: No worries, here's a link:
https://reenaverma.github.io/Local-Storage/
https://reenaverma.github.io/Local-Storage/pagination.js
https://reenaverma.github.io/Local-Storage/app.js

Comment: Ok, so I'm not 100% sure on this as I don't use Google Closure myself, however I've read some of the docs on the advanced compiler - [link here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3) - and there is a section titlled "Declaring Externs" that mentions using externs when using functions defined in external files. Could this possibly be of any help?